# App Inventor - Line width in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, app-inventor

I have an issue with drawing a line in Canvas - App Inventor. I made the codes and it is drawing the line but when I am choosing a thicker line to be drawn it is drawing with interruptions.

[image]

Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

The setup is the same but seems not working. You can see on the picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to solve your problem without the code. However, you can use Call Canvas.DrawCircle function. Just add the code in when Canvas.Dragged part.

Answer (score 0):

easy , you can use `canvas.Dragged` and then call `canvas.DrawCircle`

[image: Code Image Here]

as you can see I used both DrawLine and DrawCircle , 'cause if the LineWidth is too low then DrawCircle can not bee good choice and i used DrawLine for lower than 15 LineWidths for the better view .